# Верстка, bootstrap

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap4

Есть навбар и ниже контейнер с полем. Это поле должно заполнить всю свободную высоту. `heigth: 100vh` не учитывает НАВБАР и появляется скролл, который мне не нужен. ХЕЛП.

```css
.b-height {
  height: 100vh;
  /* ну или сколько нужно по макету */
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TODO</a>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row b-height">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #d9d9d9;">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #d9d9d9;">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. `18px` - высота navbar'a

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b-height {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 18px);
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TODO</a>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row b-height">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #d9d9d9;">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #d9d9d9;">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>TODO</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            .todo-height{
                height: 20vh;              }
            .b-height{
                height: 80vh; /* ну или сколько нужно по макету */
            }
        </style>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary todo-height">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TODO</a>
    </nav> 

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row b-height">
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #d9d9d9;">1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background: #d9d9d9;">3</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

100vh - это общая высота, её можно попробовать разбить, например, на 20 и 80vh. Или как удобно.

Comment: Не подходит, применение vh к навбару имеет печальные последствия..)

Comment: Наверное... В последний раз использовала шаблон бокового меню отсюда http://dbmast.ru/vydvigayushheesya-bokovoe-menyu-na-chistom-css Но, конечно, всё зависит от задачи